# When I run my python code my tkinter window wont respond

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a game and right now I am stuck on this part where the variable `cmd` is the command the code is given and what it should do. When I run this code, and then go to click the button it makes, it says python isn't responding and then closes.

```
while True: 
    if cmd=='P1screen':
            screen=tkinter.Tk()
            screen.update() 
    if cmd[:-1]=='Amount':
        Label(screen, bg='white', text='There are currently').grid(row=0)
        Label(screen, bg='white', text=cmd[-1]).grid(row=1)
        Label(screen, bg='white', text='players on the server').grid(row=2)
        screen.update()
    if cmd=='Ready to start?':
    
        Button(screen, bg='white', text='Start', command=Starting).grid(row=3)
        screen.update()
```

I'm not sure what to do so anyone with tkinter knowledge please lend me a hand. Thanks!

UPDATE

Here is my full script since people were asking for it:

```
import socket, tkinter
from CATF import *
# create a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

# get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()                           

port = 9999

def Starting():
    print('The game has begun')

# connection to hostname on the port.
s.connect((host, port))    
            

while True:
    cmd=s.recv(1024)
    cmd=cmd.decode('ascii')
    if cmd=='P1screen':
        screen=tkinter.Tk()
        screen.update() 
    if cmd[:-1]=='Amount':
        Label(screen, bg='white', text='There are currently').grid(row=0)
        Label(screen, bg='white', text=cmd[-1]).grid(row=1)
        Label(screen, bg='white', text='players on the server').grid(row=2)
        screen.update()
    if cmd=='Ready to start?':
        #ready=input('Press ENTER to Start')
        #if ready=='':

        Button(screen, bg='white', text='Start', command=Starting).grid(row=3)
        screen.update()
```

Comment: posting your full script might be helpful and tried using `elif`? what about restarting ur system?

Comment: don't restart the system - it isn't necessary. But post your full script.

Comment: `tkinter` isn't responding because you aren't using it correctly. Follow the tutorial at `https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html#helloworld` and go from there

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino I cant use mainloop in this scenario

Comment: Well then, run the while loop in another thread. You must run mainloop if you want the GUI to respond or even appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own event-loop instead of tkinter mainloop;
you still need to create & lay out your (static) widgets,
before entering the event-loop (& update them in the loop).

```
import tkinter as tk

from random import randint
from time import sleep

def Starting(): print('The game has begun')

screen = tk.Tk()
running = True
def stop(): 
  global running
  running = False
# Stop custom event-loop, when user closes the window:
screen.wm_protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', stop)

# Hoist widget creation & layout, outside custom event-loop:
tk.Button(screen, text='Start', command=Starting).pack()
infoLabel = tk.Label(screen, text='Label text.')
infoLabel.pack()

commands = ('Amount1', 'Amount2', 'Amount3')

updatePeriodSec = 0.1
while running:
  # Simulate receiving command over socket; pick random one:
  cmd = commands[randint(0, len(commands)-1)]
  
  if cmd[:-1] == 'Amount':
    infoLabel['text'] = f'There are {cmd[-1]} players.'
  
  # Process events once per loop:
  screen.update()
  
  # Simulating delay between updates.
  # Should probably check, if there are pending commands;
  # and e.g. sleep if there are none, else loop immediately.
  sleep(updatePeriodSec)
```